# Changing scene with Action.___() in router-flux runs constructor and ComponentWillMount but doesn't display the new Scene

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux, react-native-ios

I have a project that is set up with router-flux and I can't get my scene change to work.

As mentioned in the title the constructor for the scene I'm trying to switch to is run as well as componentWillMount but the view does not change to the next scene.

The route is set up as follows:

```
        <Provider store={store}>
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Router navigationBarStyle={{backgroundColor: bs.COLOR.main2}}
                        titleStyle={{color: '#FFF'}}
                        barButtonTextStyle={{color: '#FFF'}} barButtonIconStyle={{tintColor: '#FFF'}}>
                    <Scene key="root">
                        <Scene key="startScene" title="Start" component={StartScene} hideNavBar={false} />
                        <Scene key="myPage" initial={true} title="My Profile"} component={MyPageScene} hideNavBar={false} />
                        <Scene key="profileSettings" title="My Profile" } component={ProfileSettingsScene}/>
                    </Scene>
                </Router>
            </View>
        </Provider>);
```

and the Actions are called with

```
<TouchableHighlight activeOpacity={0.7} underlayColor="#ffffff00" onPress={()=>Actions.profileSettings()}>...</T..
```

I have a similar setup in another project that works fine and the only difference I can find is that this code is running in an integrated iOS project. I don't get any errors, the intended next scene just doesn't render.

versions:

react: 15.3.2,
react-native: 0.37.0,
react-native-router-flux: 3.37.0

Comment: No errors? The Last two scenes have a single curly bracket behind the title tag which shouldn't be there...

Comment: I get no errors or anything printed to log. Curly bracket was just my sloppy cleaning up another initial attribute. Didn't have any impact on the error when cleaned away though.